# Directives inside ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I'm building a simple angularjs app and I'm trying to implement login without page refresh.

**What I'm doing**

On init the ng-include loads the /set/save. The /set/save got the `<a fblogin>Login with Facebook</a>` in it. So when clicked the directive opens a window and when the window is closed it should change the src of the ng-include.

**The problem**

When the directive is used inside the ng-include ( ng-include src has default value on init ), nothing happens ( no errors in console, just nothing ), but when I put the directive outside the ng-include it's working fine ( see HTML code below )

HTML:

```
<div id="set-creator" ng-controller="SetCtrl">
    ........
    <div id="saveModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>

        <a href fblogin>testCase</a> 

                // ^this is working
                //but if the directive is inside ng-include, it's not working

        <ng-include src="saveTemplate"></ng-include>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
App.directive('fblogin', function() {
return {
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.click(function() {
            var win = window.open("/auth/facebook", 'popUpWindow', 'centerscreen=true');
            var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                if (win.closed) {

                    scope.saveTemplate = '/set/continue';
                    scope.$apply();


                    clearInterval(intervalID);
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    }
};
});
```

Controller:

```
App.controller("SetCtrl", ["$scope", "SetHolder",
    function($scope, SetHolder) {
        $scope.saveTemplate = '/set/save';
        $scope.test = "loaded";
    }
]);
```

And /set/save

```
You need to be logged in order to save the set.
<br />
<a fblogin>Login with Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ilVbkHVTQWBHAs5249BT?p=preview

### You got bitten by using a primitive value on the scope.

- When you put `fblogin` outside of `ngInclude` it's on the same scope of the controller.
- `ngInclude` always creates a new child scope so any directive inside it is on `a child scope`.

#### From [Understanding Scopes wiki:](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope.
>
> It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that **the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name**. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.
>
> New AngularJS developers often do not realize that **ng-repeat, ng-switch, ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes**, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always [have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m).

What happens in your case is that `scope.saveTemplate = '/set/continue';` just create a variable on the child scope which shadows `scope.saveTemplate` of the parent scope (controller).