# My carousel not working only when i am using ng-include. else its working

Tags: angularjs

```js
var AccordionApp = angular.module("Carouselapp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope) {
 
  $scope.myInterval = 50000;
  $scope.slides = [
     { image1: 'IMAGES/AngularJS.jpg', image2: 'IMAGES/BigData.jpg' },
    { image1: 'IMAGES/Mainframe.png', image2: 'IMAGES/DOTNET.png' },
    { image1: 'IMAGES/AngularJS.jpg', image2: 'IMAGES/BigData.jpg' },
    { image1: 'IMAGES/Mainframe.png', image2: 'IMAGES/DOTNET.png' }
  ];
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html />
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div >
  <carousel interval="myInterval">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
     <img ng-src="{{slide.image1}}" style="margin:auto;"> 
    </td>
    <td><img ng-src="{{slide.image2}}" style="margin:auto;">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     
           
    </slide>
  </carousel>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi,
My carousel using bootstrap is working fine when i am using a seperate page for it. but when i am including it in my index page its not working. I feel all my slides are active thats why its showing all the images.
Pls let me know how to solve this. I have spent 2 days on this already.
Thanks
The below snippet is working but when i using ng-include in div> tag and plave this in another html it stops working..
Pls help

Comment: I am very new to angular i might be doing some silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue and spend around 3 hours to get the correct answer.

Just add following line in your controller after loading you data in your controller:

```
$('#carousel').carousel('cycle');
```

Here is my working code:

```
Service.GetData('home').then(function (response) {
   $scope.data = response.data.Data;
   $('#carousel').carousel('cycle');
  }, function (error) {
     $scope.error = error.message;
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you got the same problem than that guy : [Directives inside ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369730/directives-inside-ng-include)

The ng-include create a new scope.

You can try to write :

```
$scope.myInterval = {value: 50000};
```

and use

```
<carousel interval="myInterval.value">
```

as a fix, because object and primitive inheritance dont work the same way.

Directive and scope inheritance are quite complicated, you can check the answer above for detail

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not working either. Its not even loading the images now.

Comment: What do you mean by setting the value by variable, why cannot you put the value directly in your html <carousel interval="5000">

Comment: You can but the goal was to get back the info in the parent scope, hence the variable.